# Ruby on Rails: Devise Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

What can I do to find out if a user is logged in?

Not only the current user, but all the users who are currently signed in.

Would I have to create my own function or is there an existing rails function that can take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [devise_lastseenable](https://github.com/ctide/devise_lastseenable) gem, which would track a timestamp of when the user was last active.  Then you would write a scope to find all of them within X minutes of the current time.

Another option would be to track a similar timestamp through sessions, but I'd give this gem a try first.